# Desenhar triângulos com OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl

Estou aprendendo OpenGL ES 2.0 para Android, e após certa familiarização com a ordem da programação estou tentando desenhar 2 triângulos na tela, a partir de 2 objetos diferente. É algo muito simples, mas não está dando certo, apenas meu "triangle2" é desenhado na tela.

Poderiam em ajudar?

Classe 1

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GLSurfaceView myGLSurfaceView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myGLSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);      
    myGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    myGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(new RendererClass());

    setContentView(myGLSurfaceView);

}

}
```

Classe 2 - Triângulo 1

```
public class ObjectTriangle {

int BYTES_PER_FLOAT = 4;
int shaderProgram;
FloatBuffer vertexInBuffer;

public ObjectTriangle(){

    float[] vertexArray = {

            0.0f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f

    };

    vertexInBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexArray.length*BYTES_PER_FLOAT)
                                           .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                                           .asFloatBuffer()
                                           .put(vertexArray);

}

public void inicializeObjectShaders(){

    String vertexShaderCode = "attribute vec4 a_Position;"
                            + "attribute vec4 a_Color;"
                            + "varying vec4 v_Color;"

                            + "void main(){" 
                            +     "gl_Position = a_Position;"
                            +     "v_Color = a_Color;"
                            + "}";

    String fragmentShaderCode = "precision mediump float;" 
                              + "varying vec4 v_Color;" 

                              + "void main(){" 
                              +     "gl_FragColor = v_Color;"
                              + "}";

    int vertexShaderID = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    int fragmentShaderID = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShaderID, vertexShaderCode);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShaderID, fragmentShaderCode);

    GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShaderID);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShaderID);

    shaderProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

    GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShaderID);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShaderID);

    GLES20.glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);        

}

public void setVertexAttribPointer(){

    int aPositionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_Position");
    int aColorLocation = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_Color");

    vertexInBuffer.position(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, (2+3)*BYTES_PER_FLOAT, vertexInBuffer);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);

    vertexInBuffer.position(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(aColorLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, (2+3)*BYTES_PER_FLOAT, vertexInBuffer);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(aColorLocation);

}

public void useProgram(){
    GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgram); 
}

public void draw(){
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

}
```

Classe 3 - Triângulo 2 (99% igual o triângulo1, só muda o local de 1 vértice)

```
public class ObjectTriangle2 {

int BYTES_PER_FLOAT = 4;
int shaderProgram;
FloatBuffer vertexInBuffer;

public ObjectTriangle2(){

    float[] vertexArray = {

            0.0f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
           -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f

    };

    vertexInBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexArray.length*BYTES_PER_FLOAT)
                                           .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                                           .asFloatBuffer()
                                           .put(vertexArray);

}

public void inicializeObjectShaders(){

    String vertexShaderCode = "attribute vec4 a_Position;"
                            + "attribute vec4 a_Color;"
                            + "varying vec4 v_Color;"

                            + "void main(){" 
                            +     "gl_Position = a_Position;"
                            +     "v_Color = a_Color;"
                            + "}";

    String fragmentShaderCode = "precision mediump float;" 
                              + "varying vec4 v_Color;" 

                              + "void main(){" 
                              +     "gl_FragColor = v_Color;"
                              + "}";

    int vertexShaderID = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    int fragmentShaderID = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShaderID, vertexShaderCode);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShaderID, fragmentShaderCode);

    GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShaderID);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShaderID);

    shaderProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

    GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShaderID);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShaderID);

    GLES20.glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);        

}

public void setVertexAttribPointer(){

    int aPositionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_Position");
    int aColorLocation = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_Color");

    vertexInBuffer.position(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, (2+3)*BYTES_PER_FLOAT, vertexInBuffer);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);

    vertexInBuffer.position(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(aColorLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, (2+3)*BYTES_PER_FLOAT, vertexInBuffer);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(aColorLocation);

}

public void useProgram(){
    GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgram); 
}

public void draw(){
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

}
```

Classe 4 - O Renderer

```
public class RendererClass implements Renderer {

ObjectTriangle triangle;
ObjectTriangle2 triangle2;  

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 arg0, EGLConfig config) {

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f);                

    triangle = new ObjectTriangle();
    triangle.inicializeObjectShaders();
    triangle.setVertexAttribPointer();

    triangle2 = new ObjectTriangle2();
    triangle2.inicializeObjectShaders();
    triangle2.setVertexAttribPointer();     

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 arg0, int width, int height) {

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);     

    triangle.useProgram();
    triangle.draw();    

    triangle2.useProgram();
    triangle2.draw();

}   

}
```

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com seu código, você cria dois programas exatamente iguais, um para cada objeto. O que não é necessário, e aliás, consome recursos extras desnecessariamente.

É possível utilizar o mesmo programa para desenhar quantos objetos forem necessários, apenas chamando os devidos

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(...);
```

antes das chamadas

```
GLES20.glDrawXXX(...);
```

Mesmo que você utilize dois ou três programas diferentes, você deve chamar os `glVertexAttribPointer` antes dos `glDrawXXX`, pois a informação de vértices não fica armazenada junto com o programa, conforme essa pessoa já respondeu no SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645148/what-is-the-scope-of-glvertexattribpointer-and-glenablevertexattribarray

Como você só altera o programa, e executa dois `glDrawArrays`, as duas chamadas ao método `glDrawArrays` estão efetivamente desenhando a mesma coisa na tela duas vezes, utilizando a última coisa que foi atribuída através do `glVertexAttribPointer`, que no seu caso, foram as informações do triângulo 2.

Outro detalhe é a forma com que você está utilizando o `stride`. Você está utilizando `(2+3)*BYTES_PER_FLOAT`, o que não é verdade. O `stride` deve ser a quantidade de bytes *entre* elementos consecutivos, conforme a documentação do OpenGL diz: [glVertexAttribPointer](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml).

Se você só tivesse coordenadas X, Y, X, Y, X, Y... seu `stride` seria 0. Como você tem dados diferentes intercalados, seu `stride` não será 0, mas também não será `(2+3)*BYTES_PER_FLOAT`.

Pelo que pude entender, seus dados estão da seguinte forma:

X, Y, R, G, B,
X, Y, R, G, B,
X, Y, R, G, B, ...

Assim, para os dados de coordenadas, existem 3 `floats` entre cada par de coordenadas: o `stride` para `aPositionLocation` deveria ser `3*BYTES_PER_FLOAT`.

Já para os dados das cores, existem 2 `floats` entre cada trio de cores: o `stride` para `aColorLocation` deveria ser `2*BYTES_PER_FLOAT`.

Só mais um detalhe, por questão de desempenho, se possível, é melhor criar VAO's, e utilizá-los, em vez de ficar passando seu vetor criado em Java toda vez que precisar desenhar (isso consome processamento desnecessariamente).

Assim, na hora de inicializar o objeto, basta fazer:

```
int[] buf = new int[1];
//cria um buffer, e armazena seu id em buf[0]
GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, buf, 0);

//armazena o id do buffer em uma variável, para não precisar utilizar um array sempre
int bufId = buf[0];

//- Supondo que vertices seja um vetor float[] com as informações dos meus vértices
//- Se você já tivesse um Buffer, a chamada FloatBuffer.wrap é desnecessária
//- O * BYTES_PER_FLOAT é porque glBufferData precisa do tamanho em bytes, e não em elementos
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                    bufId);
GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                    vertices.length * BYTES_PER_FLOAT,
                    FloatBuffer.wrap(vertices),
                    GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Para que, na hora de desenhar, seja preciso fazer apenas isto, em vez de passar o vetor inteiro de novo:

```
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufId);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(...);
GLES20.glDrawXXX(...);
```